# Filtering executed SQL queries on application server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-injection

First of all, I know this is bad practice but regardless I'm still looking for an answer.

In our web application we have a textarea where the user can write SQL to bring in custom data sets and view them in a chart. The way this works is essentially taking the written string and executing it as a query. What I'm looking for is everything I need to implement in our application server back end security wise as to disallow the execution of queries that produce results other than `SELECT` type queries.

The user won't be able to execute any type of `SELECT` query he wants since the app server backend expends the returned result set to have 2 columns named `X_FIELD` and `Y_FIELD` so we're not so much worried about the user being able to view data as much as him executing SQL that will break the database.

What we thought of doing is parsing the string for keywords such as `DROP`, `ALTER`, `CREATE` etc. Are there specific things that we have to look out for? Is there a tool/library that automates this? We're using java for our back end code.

Comment: How about creating user with very restricted access to database?

Comment: Do you know if it's running SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh As it says in the tags, the application can run on both servers (even more but the tags wouldn't fit) so this has to cover both of them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! (Too often products not involved are tagged...)

Comment: What if the user executes: `select username as X_FIELD, password as Y_FIELD from customers`?

Comment: Read Only users/roles can be created in either Oracle or MSSQL.  create the Role in the system and set the connection string of the Application requesting the SQL to a user assigned to a read only role?  I get trying to handle some stuff in the app layer, but the Engines have a robust security layer, take advantage of it.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic The Y_FIELD is retrievied user the `ResultSet` function `getInt()` and since the passwords are encrypted strings it will throw an exception making the query invalid.

Comment: No, that is just a demonstrative example. It could then be `select salary as X_FIELD, bonus as Y_FIELD from employees where type = 'CEO'`.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Indeed it could be many things. I'm still waiting for my supervisor for a re-talk about if we should implement this but still

Comment: We had a similar function in an off the shelf app.  One user did a select * from a_very_large_table and froze the database for everyone else while it took hours to complete.  When we killed the session it crashed the app server.   We don't allow that anymore....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering queries can be done at the application level but it requires much more database-specific expertise than creating separate security systems for each database.

As an example, I created an [open source program](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer#example) that can do this for Oracle.  It won't solve your problem but the code can at least help explain why this is a bad idea.

First, it's important to understand that Oracle SQL syntax is *much* more complicated than most programming languages, such as Java.
  Oracle has 2175 keywords and almost none of them are reserved.  Forget about parsing SQL - none of the existing 3rd party parsers are accurate enough to do this securely.

Luckily a full parser is not needed for this task.  Oracle syntax is structured in such a way that any statement can be classified with only 8 tokens, excluding
 whitespace and comments.

But building a [tokenizer](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/tokenizer.plsql) and a
 [statement classifier](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/statement_classifier.plsql) is still difficult.  That solution will handle
 unusual kinds of selects, such as `(select * from dual)` or `with asdf as (select 1 a from dual) select a from asdf;`.  But even a `SELECT` statement can cause
 changes to the database; either through PL/SQL hidden in a function or type, or locking rows through a `for update`.

And don't forget to remove the (sometimes optional) [terminator](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/statement_terminator.plsql).  They work fine
 in most IDEs, but they are not allowed in dynamic SQL.  Don't just remove the last characters, or the last token, because some `SELECT` statements allow semicolons in the middle.

---

That's a lot of work for just one database!  If you want to use this method to implement security policies you need almost 100% accuracy.  Very few people are fanatical enough about *any* database to build this.  There's no chance you can do this for multiple databases.

Comment: Thank you. I'll convey that the correct thing to do is to NOT implement this and that there is no way to make it secure.